# Multiple actions within one while loop python

Tags: python, while-loop

I need help with an experimental python bot that allows one to be afk and grind discord bots. (And I'm new to programming so please don't judge).
Im trying to get all my def... into one variable but so all def... run at the same time.

```
    import pyautogui
    import time
    
    time.sleep(10)
    
    x = 0
    
    def a():
        pyautogui.typewrite(";sell")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite("vf")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite("t!fish")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(5)
    
    def b():
        pyautogui.typewrite("owoh")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite("owob")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(15)
    
    def c():
        pyautogui.typewrite("pls beg")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite("pls dig")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite("pls fish")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite("pls hunt")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(35)
    
    def d():
        pyautogui.typewrite("owo pray")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite(";fish")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite("pls hunt")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(300)
    
    def e():
        pyautogui.typewrite("pls work")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        pyautogui.typewrite("$p")
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(4500)
    
    def main():
        a()
        b()
        c()
        d()
        e()
    
    while x < 10:
        main()
        x +=1
```

So I'm basically trying to get all run at once so that every 5 seconds it sends the 5s items but also starts writes the 15s and 35 etc. during the same time. As it is now it sends the 5s items waits 5 seconds and moves on the the 15s items.

Comment: If you want to run multiple functions simultaneously, you need to learn about threading in python first.

Comment: Seems like you want some sort of multithreading or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Or scheduling, which might be viable in a single thread.

Comment: I don't think you need threading here.  I suggest you look closely at the `schedule` package, which lets you register timed callbacks, and then handles the scheduling.  https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i run all def... at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Here's how this would work with the `schedule` module.

```
import pyautogui
import schedule
import time

def say(*words):
    for s in words:
        pyautogui.typewrite(s)
        pyautogui.press("enter")

def a():
    say(';sell','vf','t!fish')

def b():
    say('owoh', 'owob')

def c():
    say("pls beg", 'pls dig', 'pls fish', 'pls hunt')

def d():
    say('owo pray', ';fish', 'pls hunt')

def e():
    say('pls work', '$p')

def main():
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(a)
    schedule.every(15).seconds.do(b)
    schedule.every(35).seconds.do(c)
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(d)
    schedule.every(75).minutes.do(e)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

main()
```

Comment: How can I install schedule in pycharm? The '$ pip install schedule' doesn't work in the terminal

Comment: You don't type the `$`.  That's just showing you the prompt.

Comment: but even if I type 'pip install schedule' id doesn't work

Comment: It somehow worked getting schedule but now I don't get any output into discord

Comment: What window has the keyboard focus?  This is just going to send keys to whatever window has focus.  Are you switching to the browser?

Comment: Yes I am, but I still get no output. It takes about 20 seconds and then it says that the program ran successfully

Comment: What happens if you bring up Notepad, start this app, and then give Notepad the focus?  Do you see the strings?

Comment: I tried it on Norepad and I still get no output

Comment: I made a mistake.   You need `say(*words)`, not `say(words)`.  See if that makes the difference.